# Getting all objects in a class without using loops django 1.8

Tags: python, django

I have a template `navbar.html` where I store the template for navbar and then include it in `index.html` which is the base template.

`views.py`

```
class NaverDetailView(generic.DetailView):
model = Naver
naver = Naver.objects.order_by('-artist_name')[:10]
template_name = 'feature/detailgenrenaver.html' 
context_object_name = 'naver'
```

`detailnaver.html`

```
<div id="wrapper1">
<iframe width="1024" height="500" src="{{ naver.videoid }}" frameborder="0"   allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

`navbar.html`

```
 {% for navloop in naver_set.all %}
 <nav class="navbar" data-tap-toggle="false" role="navigation">
   <div class="col_2 rightside">
          <img src="img/rafa.jpg" width="120" height="83">
          <p>image1</p>

          <img src=naver.videoimage" width="120" height="83" >
          <p>naver.artist_name</p>
    </div>
 </nav>
 {% endfor %}
```

`urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [

url(r'^$', views.rock_and_feat, name='rock_and_feat'),
url(r'^trending/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='naver'),
]
```

`index.html`

```
<html>
<head>{% include "feature/navbar.html" %}</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

My problem is, when I use the `for` loop in `navbar.html`, is lists all the objects in `Naver`, But I want to be able to refer to the objects individually with maybe the id reference like `naver.videoimage(id=1)` or something like that and without the for loop so that it doesn't list the objects multiple times.

Comment: Why do you need to refer to them by id?

Comment: like for example if I want to place one object of the model `Naver` under navbar menu item `recent` and another object under menu item `popular`. If I am not able to reference them by some sort of key(id or name) I'll just have a list of items without being able place them.

Comment: Sounds like you should handle that in your view and pass separate context variables for `recent` and `popular` items.

Comment: Yes I know. That is what my question was.Is there a way to do that.

Comment: `Naver.objects.get(id=...)`?  I'm talking about the view, mind you, not the template. The template is not suited for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could filter your object selection down to only the items you want in your view.  Then only pass the selected items onto your template.

Let's say I have a project named get_by_pk with an application named     by_pk.  Here is the by_pk model's file:

/get_by_pk/by_pk/models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Naver(models.Model):
    value_to_reference = models.CharField(max_length=10,primary_key=True)
    another_field = models.TextField(max_length=500)
```

Then in your view you could select a subset
/get_by_pk/by_pk/views.py

```
from by_pk.models import Naver

    #...whatever view you want
    only_these = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    filtered_objects = Naver.objects.filter(value_to_reference__in=only_these).values()
    #pass filtered_objects to template
```

Here is a link about querying models:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/

Comment: what are the parameters you are using in `only_these`? `['a', 'b', 'c']`? And what about the second part of the question? How do I list the objects I want in a template without the for loop? Because the for loop would render them multiple times.

Comment: @turtle I used 'only_these' as a list containing the primary keys I want for the object query.  I think that is what you are aiming for with  "id reference like naver.videoimage(id=1)" .  You mentioned you didn't want to list all objects.  I don't know why it is listing objects multiple times from your example.

Comment: Yes using this method I will get a list of all the id's I need but what I need is to reference those id's individually in the template.Like if I want the image of object with id =3, I can get it by using the id. And about the second part, the for loop will list all the objects but the `nav` `div` will be displayed multiple times. i.e as many times as the loop runs.